# Can I upgrade cmd.exe on Windows 8.1 to the Windows 10 version?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, cmd.exe

I work on a Windows 8.1 Enterprise PC. I Would like to upgrade my Command Line terminal (cmd.exe) to the one offered in the latest version of Windows 10, which has many handy features that the old one lacks. EDIT: I mean UI features like the automatic word wrap and the ability to maximize in the whole window. Is it possible? 
I would prefer the traditional cmd.exe and not PowerShell.

Comment: Which features are you looking for in Win10 cmd.exe that aren't in the 8.1 cmd.exe? It's likely they exist, but have a different command name.

Comment: What you want is not possible.  If you can use PowerShell instead, then PowerShell 5.12 and/or PowerShell Core 6.x, can be used instead on Windows 8.1.  The improvements to the command prompt are connected to the kernel.